# LastUsed is sometimes blank or $null

Tags: powershell

`$Oldest = $Results | Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 'Main' } | Sort-Object LastUsed | Select-Object -First 10`

Above my command tries to find the 10 oldest dates and then I act on them. My issue is that sometimes the date is `blank or $null`

How can I push the `blank or $null` to the top of the list and find them with the oldest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should place `$null` values first in the sort order, before the objects with the oldest dates.

```
Sort-Object { [bool] $_.LastUsed }, LastUsed
```

The first [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) criterion, `[bool] $_.LastUsed`, maps `$null` values to `$false` and non-null values to `$true`, and since `$false` sorts before `$true`, objects with `$null` values in their `.LastUsed` property are placed first in the sort order.

Those with non-null `.LastUsed` values sort according to those values, thanks to the second sort criterion (property).